# How to display particular column of table in a loop & use those values anywhere

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here I'm getting all columns from table by using this:

```
        $product = array();
        $crtItems = $this->cart->contents();
        foreach($crtItems as $crtItem){
             $product[] = $this->pmodel->getRows($crtItem['id']); 
         }
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($product);         
        exit();
```

I want to display only one column (names), in a loop, from table for example I want to display all names (column) from table; here I'm using this code but I get an error

> "Undefined index: name"

Code:

```
        $product = array();
        $crtItems = $this->cart->contents();
        foreach($crtItems as $crtItem){
             $product[] = $this->pmodel->getRows($crtItem['id']); 
         }
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($product['name']);         
        exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    $crtItems = $this->cart->contents();
    for($i=0; $i<count($crtItems); $i++){
         echo $crtItems[$i]['name']; } 
     
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($product['name']);         
    exit();
```

and show the answer of this code:

```
 print_r($crtItems); exit();
```

Comment: var_dump($product[0]['name']);   it is just displaying one record with index 0; I want to dispaly all indexs with column name[name]

Comment: echo '<pre>'; var_dump($product);   exit();  this one showing all records with respected ids; I just want to display only names not all

Comment: its showing error "Undefined offset: 0, Undefined offset: 1, Undefined offset: 2," it is fetching all record but showing errors

Comment: Its showing error to add bunch of codes in Question; you can see online I have uploaded image of result at this:   https://ibb.co/jGWcR5h

Comment: And here is link of your code's result:  https://ibb.co/yBgdrBj

Comment: remove $product = array(); line and   $product[] = $this->pmodel->getRows($crtItem['id']);  than try my edited answer and let me know result of print_r($crtItems); exit();